# Does changing your trainer name free it for a different user?

Tags: pokemon-go

An update for Pokémon GO was released on August 8th, 2016, allowing users to change their trainer name once. I'm considering doing this, but my first account I have since abandoned has the name I'd prefer to use. If I change the trainer name of that abandoned account to something different, could my current account use the abandoned account's previous name?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you have changed your name someone else can take it.

Comment: Can you add where this information is from?

Comment: @mafu Can't find the source, just common sense and a lot of people saying the same thing.

Comment: It's not common sense. It is not uncommon that it is not possible to create accounts with names that were previously used.